# How to add image in front of screen - Android

Tags: java, android

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGHkn.jpg)

How can I add images and videos like this? Is there any keyword to look for tutorials?

Comment: Just add an ImageView matching parent size in your layout?

Comment: This picture appears in every apps. No matter which app is open, these pictures and videos are in front of it.

Comment: Maybe this post can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top